# Where are the addresses of the sender and receiver in TX info?

Tags: transactions, signature, send-transaction

In the data returned by https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

where are the addresses of **the sender and receiver**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transaction object can have multiple instructions of different types, such as `createAccount`, `transfer` etc. Since you're looking for a sender and receiver, I'd assume you need answer for `transfer`. You can get the response in the following way and filter out receiver and sender. In this TypeScript example, I'm assuming the transaction object only contains one instruction, and that instruction is transfer.

```
const getTransferDetails = async (tx: string) => {
  const data = {
    method: 'getTransaction',
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    id: "1",
    params: [
      tx,
      { encoding: 'jsonParsed', commitment: "finalized" }
    ],
  }

  const response = await fetch("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })


  const json = await response.json()
  if (!json.result) {
    return { receiver: null, sender: null }
  }

  // Notice I'm getting the zero index, because like I mentioned earlier, I'm assuming this transaction consists of only one transfer instruction
  const instruction = json.result.transaction.message.instructions[0]

  // This will give you an object containing "destination", "source" and "amount"
  const { destination, source, amount } = instruction.parsed.info

  return { receiver: destination, sender: source, amount }
}
```

Note that this won't work for SPL transfers, you would need to filter the data out differently.

For SPL transfers, filter it in this way:

```
const instructions = json.result.transaction.message.instructions
const transferInstruction = instructions.filter((instruction: any) => ["transfer", "transferChecked"].includes(instruction.parsed.type))[0]
const receiverAccount = transferInstruction.parsed.info.destination
const source = transferInstruction.parsed.info.source
let amount = transferInstruction.parsed.info.amount
if (!amount) {
    amount = transferInstruction.parsed.info.tokenAmount.amount
}
amount = Number(amount) / 1000000 // USDC Decimals (6)
if (!receiverAccount || !amount) {
    console.log(instructions)
}
return {
    sender: source,
    amount: amount,
    receiver: receiverAccount,
}
```

Rest remains the same. Just be sure to replace decimals with your token's (which you can also get in the response)

You can also use `@solana/web3.js` library and use `getTransaction` method directly from the `Connection` object then filter it out instead of making a raw network request like this :)

### Reference:

[Transaction Structure](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#transaction-structure)

Comment: You mean that that will only work for the transfers in SOL?

Comment: **Note that this won't work for SPL transfers, you would need to filter the data out differently.** --> how? I need to parse transactions in USDT, USDC tokens too. And, possibly, 1-2 other stablecoins as well. Transfers will be sent from  ordinary or normal accounts

Comment: @Kristi Yes, this example was only for SOL transfers. I have edited it to include SPL transfer as well.

Comment: is the only difference in this case between parsing SOL and SPL token the `amount` of decimal places? SOL has 9, and a token has 6?

Comment: ** the decimal places of the `amount`

Comment: Yeah almost, token required one additional check for amount there tho, you can always run these codes yourself and log values to figure it out, I hope to approach is clear now!

Comment: What do you "almost"? What else?

Comment: As long as one doesn't use a decimal in the DB or in the code-base, and instead one stores everything in integers - `lamports` - there's no need for an additional check, right?

Comment: I said almost because different tokens have different decimals and the instruction type is also different, as you can see in the example. 

And I couldn't quite understand what you meant by the last comment, which check and where lamports came in here?

Comment: `by the last comment, which check and where lamports came in here?` - I mean, if you  store in the DB lamports (integers) rather than the decimal amounts of SOL or tokens, and operate with lamports throught your code too, then it won't matter how many decimal places a token has. Right?

Comment: Namely, this line `amount = Number(amount) / 1000000 // USDC Decimals (6)` will become this `amount = Number(amount)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141720/discussion-between-bolt-and-kristi).

Comment: Why won't you answer here?

Comment: Extended discussions in comments is not really a good idea. But overall I said this in the chat discussion: Lamports and tokens are different things. 1 Billion Lamports = 1 SOL. So this only works for SOL. For tokens, they have different decimals, so yes if you use decimals everywhere then the extra division won't be required. But it doesn't make a lot of sense because in most places, you would be using the amount itself, lets say to show it in the UI or fetching it etc. Only when you send it to the blockchain, then the division is required.

Comment: `Lamports and tokens are different things. 1 Billion Lamports = 1 SOL. So this only works for SOL.` -- what is it that works for only SOL? Any Solana API **always** returns any amount in lamports. Therefore, how does it matter whether you make a request to API for a) SOL b) token? You'll always get back `amount` fields in lamports. And you'd then store an amount **in lamports** in DB too, as integers. That's it.

Comment: How to then display this on UI - is a different matter. I may be fine displaying it in lamports. I may not need to display anything on UI at all

Comment: You're confusing here. Solana API returns amount in lamport for Solana only. For other tokens the value is in [token_amount] ** 10 * [token_decimal].